# History of past linked servers on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Few of my earlier linked servers got deleted/lost and I am unable to see them now on SQL Server. Is there a way to know which linked servers existed in past and who dropped them?

Comment: Not easily. The definitions are stored in a system table in `master`, so if you have a backup of that, and you can set up a new instance where you can [restore it](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql), you should be able to query `sys.servers` from there. Without a backup, it's pretty much hopeless. Knowing *who* dropped them is entirely impossible without some active form of auditing, as far as I know; even if you had a full transaction log, that usually just records that "dbo" did it, which is no help.

Comment: You could try this, but it won't tell you who dropped the linked servers: SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE AllocUnitName IN ('sys.sysxsrvs.cl','sys.syslnklgns.cl');